# How to use custom hexadecimal color to display text

Tags: go

I am using [this library](https://github.com/fatih/color) for applying colors on strings printed.

I can use simple standard colors as:

```
color.New(color.FgBlue)
```

Is it possible to use my custom colors in this library?
Example, I have a hexadecimal color - #00FFFF
Is it possible to use this with the library?

Comment: Not all terminals support arbitrary colors. Most support a standard 16-color palette, some support 256 colors, and some support full 24-bit true color. Based on the documentation of that library, it supports only the basic 16 color palette.

Comment: The very description of the project answers the question: "an ANSI color package for Go."

Answer (score 0):

Fatih's color library does not support RGB colors, only the standard 16 ANSI colors.

True color support varies depending on your terminal emulator. One library I found that supports "truecolor" is https://github.com/wayneashleyberry/truecolor. You can find more information about how it works and a list of supported terminal emulators at https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728.